# Javascript Confirm Before execute javascript in Chrome

Tags: javascript

The function `hideWord()` in function does not work when I run `checkWord()` function. `promt()` expects the function to finish.
What can I do.

I would like the function `promt()` to work after the function `hideWord()` before the function `checkWord()` works. Please compare Firefox and Chrome:

```js
function checkWord() {
    hideWord();
    var answer = prompt("please you write word see?");
}

function hideWord() {
    document.getElementById('takistoskopContainer').innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<div id="takistoskopContainer">Must this text empty before promt!</div>
<br><br><button type="button" onclick="checkWord();">click me!</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dreamman/0o56etzk/

[image: problem image]

Comment: So first `hideWord`, then `prompt` and then `checkWord`, right????

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as you current example doesn't even run.

Comment: Yes milan chheda.

Comment: Works correct in Firefox, but **not** in Chrome!

Comment: yes skobaljic. Chrome problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am solve this problem setTimeout():

```
function checkWord() {
    hideWord();
    setTimeout(function() {
       var answer = prompt("please you write word see?");
    },0)
}
```